# Show archived elements in table

Tags: tables

I`m having an issue with the current project. We have a table with some "jobs". Once a job is completed it can be archived.

I have created a switch to "See archived jobs" that I thought it would hide current jobs in the existing table and only show the archived one. But the business managers asked for "a smarter way to allow to have both current and archived jobs merged"

Do you know any examples of how archived elements are presented?
I was thinking of having two switches one to view only archived elements and one to see both but I find it somewhat weird.

If I show them both in a table do I order them on their original date ? Or show them on the bottom or top ?

Comment: What is the table used for? And what is wrong with a separate list or view for archived items, like WhatsApp does?

Answer (score 1):

What about having all items still listed but having archived items muted in color so they look different. Also if they have drop-downs from the table then the options on the dropdown can change based on the `isArchived` status or you can disable buttons in the drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

StackExchange does this in a manner kind of @Raqem told but in the way presented below with the reputation tab on profiles as you may see.

[image: SE photo]

Simply by having a single checkbox for archived jobs would be enough this way to include them on listing or not. It's the simplest solution I can think of and you'd better keep their time relevance in order to keeping track of their presence.

Answer (score 0):

You've said:

> I have created a switch to "See archived jobs" that I thought it would hide current jobs in the existing table and only show the archived one. But the business managers asked for "a smarter way to allow to have both current and archived jobs merged"

This suggests your switch chooses between archived OR current jobs. They have specifically asked to see jobs merged...could your switch not just ADD the archived jobs to the list? as well as the current jobs?

You're right that you might need and indicator, to show the job state (archived/current) there are many ways to do this, ranging from a column with a textual representation of the state, to a colour on the row or text background, icons, etc etc.

I'd first decide what data you want to show and when, then worry about how to display it.